# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.wrapRefArray(java.lang.Object[])'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-operator

I'm trying to deploy the Apache Spark/Scala code to the GKE cluster, and it fails the Scala version issue.

Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/spark:v3.3.2
COPY target/*-shaded.jar  /opt/spark/jars/app.jar
ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark
ENV PATH $PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
ENV JAR $SPARK_HOME/jars/app.jar
ENV MAIN_CLASS=com.example.exe.SparkExample
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.exe</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkExample</artifactId>

    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <organization>
        <name>example</name>
        <url>https://example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.13.10</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.13</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>3.3.2</spark.version>
        <org.apache.logging.log4j.version>2.19.0</org.apache.logging.log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Read application.conf file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgres DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shadedbuild</id>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.exe.SparkExample</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm getting the below error in the DEV cluster using this maven command(mvn clean -P shadedbuild -B package)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.wrapRefArray(java.lang.Object[])'
```

If I use this maven command(mvn clean -B package) and get the below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Scala signature package has wrong version expected: 5.0 found: 5.2 in scala.collection.immutable.package
```

Comment: What's the Spark and Scala version of your Spark cluster?

Comment: We are using Kubernetes Operator for Apache Spark(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) and deployment using the Helm(version 3+) package.

Comment: I have updated the Scala version, and it looks like it's working.        <scala.version>2.12.12</scala.version>
<scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>

Comment: It's working fine(Scala version 2.12.12)

Comment: Then it means the cluster you have installed is running with Scala 2.12, or the way you use it at least is with Scala 2.12 and your code must use this version as well. I recommend spending a bit of time understanding what Spark version you're using and how you can change it, same for Scala version